# is there a way in JavaScript to create an object where the object keys have the same name as the variables used for the value?

Tags: javascript, object, variables, mapping, vuex

similar to using mapFunction(['name']) in vuex.

while learning vuex functionalities i came across its mapfunctions where it could map the desired property with the same name or a different name.

i want to achienve a simalar where the name and the value of the variables gets mapped to the object as it key-value pairs respectively.

is it already possible in vanilla javaScript?

references:
[vuex documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper)
[vuex mapping guide article](https://blog.logrocket.com/a-complete-guide-to-mapping-in-vuex/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20mapping%20in%20Vuex,with%20test%20data%20in%20state.)

ps: please check out the references for clearer explanation of the functionality

ex->

```
`
  variable var_name1='var_value1'
  variable var_name2='var_value2'
  //note this is the format of the vuex where the name of a mapped property will remain the same      
  obj={[var_name1,var_name2]}

 
//the above should be equivalent to this
 obj={
       var_name1='var_value1',
       var_name2='var_value2',

   }


  

`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const var_name1='var_value1'
const var_name2='var_value2'

const obj = {var_name1,var_name2}

console.log(obj)
console.log(obj.var_name1)
console.log(obj.var_name2)
```